# OpenRailwayMap not functioning with OpenLayers 2

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2

I am trying for several days now to integrate a basic OpenRailwayMap into a project using OpenLayers 2 API but it's simply not working. I followed all the steps mentioned [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API) and ended up with something like this:

http://codepen.io/payamcf/pen/XKPrvm

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/51209/openrailwaymap-not-functioning-with-openlayers2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the problem was in the attribution and projection I already fixed the error [here](http://codepen.io/payamcf/pen/mEKpQj) (the documentation is not really clear on this part)

also in case anyone wants to integrate it with leaflet api, it also had some issues which I fixed [here](http://codepen.io/payamcf/pen/YWOVXE) :) cheers.